# Error in Loading Avro File to Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, avro

I am trying to load [this avro file](https://github.com/Appboy/currents-examples/blob/master/sample-data/Avro/users.behaviors.app.SessionStart.avro) into BigQuery (using the UI), and I continually get the error:

`Error while reading data, error message: The Apache Avro library failed to parse the header with the following error: Cannot have bytes of negative length: -28 File: bigstore/bigquery-prod-upload-us/prod-scotty-685302658274-63cdb063-e24f-4423-b822-5312e0d9496a`

Even when I try to create a table from an avro file written from a json file I manually wrote, BigQuery butchers the schema.  Is there something about trying to write binary files into BQ that I am not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encountered similar issue when loading the `AVRO` via **Google Cloud Storage**.

You may try and consider below workaround:

You may directly upload the file on **BigQuery UI** as shown below,

[image]

and it will be successfully loaded.

[image]

*PS: I used the same file from your reference as is.*

Comment: I was actually able to get it to work. There was some corruption that happened before I uploaded it to GCS when I was trying to inspect the contents of the file. I had never worked with avro so wanted to see what the structure was like.